# Paypal Instant Payment Notification need to match payer order with payment

Tags: php, paypal

Trying to implement Paypal instant payment notification https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/#use-ipn-in-your-checkout-flow

Situation is following:

1) visitor wants to access to database (visitor enters something to check if entered data exists in database)

2) i collect visitor's entered data, record them in mysql, create some token, also record in mysql

3) add the token to data, i send to paypal.

4) after successful payment i allow the visitor access to database and show result of visitor's entered data. So need to know what the visitor entered/ordered.

To Paypal i send data like this:

```
$data['return'] = 'https://www.my-website.info/payment-successful.php?response='. $token_to_send_to_paypal;//here we can put URL when payment is Successful.
$data['cancel_return'] = 'https://www.my-website.info/payment-cancelled.php';//here we can put cancel URL when payment is not completed.
$data['notify_url'] = 'https://www.my-website.info/payment-notify.php';//PayPal call this file for ipn
$data['item_number'] = $token_to_send_to_paypal;
```

Then

```
$query_string = http_build_query($data);//http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string
```

And then redirect to paypal IPN

```
header( 'location:'. $paypal_url. '?'. $query_string );
```

After successful payment from Paypal i get some data back. I see that i get back `item_number=the same as token i created sent to paypal`.

The above is the only way how at the moment i can match visitor's order with the payment. But possible(?) problem is that visitor also knows the token.

Any idea / better way how to match visitor's order with payment? I mean how to send my token to Paypal and get back the token in Paypal response?

Answer (score 1):

> But possible(?) problem is that visitor also knows the token.

Why is this a problem? This is not a problem. Visitors cannot create verifiable IPNs.

The real answer is you should switch to a better checkout and not use IPN at all, for anything important, because then you wouldn't need it. Here is a better checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

With that better checkout, here is the capture API you will be calling from your server: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/

There will then be no need for IPN.